# APIREST server nodejs

Tags: node.js

I created an API rest server here is my route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pg = require('pg');
const path = require('path');
const connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL | 'postgres://user:password@host:port/database';
router.put('/', (req, res, next) => {

  const results = [];
    // Grab data from http request
  const data = {cpu: req.body.cpu, ram: req.body.ram};
  // Get a Postgres client from the connection pool
  pg.connect(connectionString, (err, client, done) => {
    // Handle connection errors
    if(err) {
      done();
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({success: false, data: err});
    }
    // SQL Query > Update Data
    client.query('UPDATE cpuram SET cpu=($1), ram=($2)',
    [data.cpu, data.ram]);
    // SQL Query > Select Data
    const query = client.query("SELECT * FROM cpuram ORDER BY 1 ASC");
    // Stream results back one row at a time
    query.on('row', (row) => {
    results.push(row);
    });
    // After all data is returned, close connection and return results
    query.on('end', function() {
      done();
      return res.json(results);
    });
  });
});



/* GET home page. */
//router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
//  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
//});

module.exports = router;
```

When I want to send a query that has the purpose of updating my database psql with this command:

> curl -X PUT --data "cpu=50&ram=10" URL

He reminds me of this error:

> {"success":false,"data":{"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":5432}}